# phantomjs fails to start with supervisord

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, supervisord

I recently added a `selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS()` object to my bot, for scraping purposes. But when I start my bot using the `supervisord`, it immediately crashes with error 127. I was searching everywhere, but didnt found any relevant info. I have all required libraries installed (`libfreetype6` and `libfontconfig`).

This occurs only when I start my bot script via supervisor, and I need it for autostarting/restarting purposes.

Exact error I get: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was 127`

PhantomJS version: 2.1.1 (installed via npm)

npm version: 5.6.0

Lines of code starting the webdriver:

```
self.utilities = {} # this happens inside the class
self.phantom_path = '/home/maxlunar/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs'
self.utilities.update({'webdriver': PhantomJS(executable_path=self.phantom_path)})
```

I can provide additional info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in wrong executable. I was using `...phantomjs/bin/phantomjs`, but correct binary is `...phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs`